# UITableView crashes on setting data to custom label

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using a custom label inside a table view cell.When I am trying to populate it with data from a array, the data is displayed but the app crashes when I scroll the table View.

The array I set in viewDidLoad

```
    tempArray=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Alert 1",@"Alert 2",@"Alert 3",@"Alert 4",@"Alert 5",@"Alert 6",@"Alert 7",@"Alert 8",@"Alert 9",@"Alert 10",nil];
```

Table View method

```
 else if (tableView.tag==2) {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

         contentLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, 2, 170, 24)];
        contentLabel.numberOfLines =0;
         contentLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:11];
        contentLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.6];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:contentLabel];


    }
    contentLabel.text = [tempArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];//crashes here 
     return cell;
}
```

Crash Log

```
        *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 10 beyond bounds [0 .. 9]'
```

Comment: could you show your crash log?

Comment: tempArray  element must be string value. i think you should use a custom table cell instead of adding it at initialization step. post your crash report here

Comment: check weather tempArray contain element with index equal to indexPath.row?

Comment: check number of rows in this method...     - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

Comment: contentLabel.text = (tempArray.count > indexPath.row) ? tempArray[indexPath.row] : @"";

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons:

1. tempArray doesn't contain element with index equal to indexPath.row
2. tempArray contains element with such index but it's not a NSString object.

Answer (score 0):

According to the crash log, you are asking the array for 10th object, whereas array has objects only from 0 to 9.

So make sure the numberOfRowsInSection returns 10.

Answer (score 0):

Please retain the tempArray array, arrayWithObjects is autorelease, then check tableview's other delegate, for example numberOfRowsInSection and so on.